# Cache Image swift

Tags: swift, firebase, caching

I try cache An image from An URL from my firebase storage. if I Print my url in function "downloadImage" I can see that I get image URL. But I Print my url in my function getImage, then nothing display.

Here I my Image Service:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ImageService {
    
    static let cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    static let storage = Storage.storage()
    static let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    // Downloading image with URL
    static func downloadImage(withURL url:URL, completion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage?, _ url:URL)->()) {
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, responseURL, error in
            var downloadedImage:UIImage?
            
            if let data = data {
                downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data)
                
            }
            if downloadedImage != nil {
                cache.setObject(downloadedImage!, forKey: url.absoluteString as NSString)
               
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(downloadedImage, url)
                
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
    // Get the downloaded image
    static func getImage(withURL url:URL?, completion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage?, _ url:URL)->()) {
        if let _url = url {
            if let image = cache.object(forKey: _url.absoluteString as NSString) {
                completion(image, _url)
                print("HEJSAN\(String(describing: url))")
            } else {
                downloadImage(withURL: _url, completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Set the retrieved image for the UIImageView
    static func setImage(imageView image: UIImageView, imageURL url: String) {
        getImage(withURL: URL(string: url)) { retrievedImage, error in
            image.image = retrievedImage
        }
    }
```

This how I try display it in my VC:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        ImageService.setImage(imageView: logoImage, imageURL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/shutappios.appspot.com/o/LogoImage%2FShutAppLogo.jpg?alt=media&token=13216931-418f-486a-9702-2985b262ab08")
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure the question is clear. *But I Print my url in my function getImage*? The getImage function as a url parameter you pass in - are you stating that if you pass a url to that function the url is empty within the function? Have you added a breakpoint within each function and stepped through the code to see where it's failing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understood well your question but based on what you said it is normal that the getImage when it is called the first time that will execute `downloadImage`  because there will be no image in the cache yet but it will have an image the second time called. maybe the issue here is that you are trying to get the image from the cache before the downloadImage completed because its code is happening on the background async does mean if you are trying to get the cash after that straightaway without waiting. More likely it will not be ready so if you want to make sure that is not going to happen I think you need to add completion to your setImage func something like this:

```
static func setImage(
    imageView image: UIImageView,
    imageURL url: String,
    completion: (() -> ())? = nil) {
    getImage(withURL: URL(string: url)) { retrievedImage, error in
        image.image = retrievedImage
        completion?()
    }
}
```

this example it will print your log from the getImage as expected the first time is downloading the second is getting from the cache.

```
 ImageService.setImage(imageView: imageView, imageURL: imageURL) {
    ImageService.setImage(imageView: self.imageView, imageURL: imageURL)
 }
```

Please note this just an example to give you idea about what could be the issue behind this I hope it will help you!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now if I run my simulator I get my print "image stored" and when go to an another page and turn of my Internet and then go back to the page their I have my image my print say "Image from cache". So in someway it works. But if I close my app and run the simulator again whitout internet connection my image not show up. Should the image be displayed after restart or am I wrong?